# How to handle special characters like pipe (|) in REST API URL path without sending an encoded values in java?

Tags: java, spring, rest, cxf, path-parameter

URL mapping is:

```
@path(value = "/article/{articleName}")

@GET
```

Here `'articleName'` contains vertical bar (`|`). So when I hit the URL I get `400 Bad Request`.

Possible solutions that I know are,

Use URL encoding.
Use of `@RequestParam` instead of `@PathVariable`.
But above solution are not possible for me.

Is there any other solution like (using a regular expression or changing the mapping or any explicit filter etc) to the problem?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is in your client request instead of in your server code. How are you making your request to the endpoint? A vertical bar is not a reserved character in a URI and does not need to be encoded.

Comment: `@POST` might work, though a terrible kludge.

Answer (score 0):

URL's can not contain | as a character.
If you think you really need it you could do a couple things

Use the ASCII table number instead for example if avaible, wich it isn't in this case. For the character within the URL bar encoding specification you are allowed to use   %7C representing the pipe. Depending on your application it may be rather smart to not use or allow this. But it is possible You could also consider to use base64 encoding and decode base64 after the API. fA== would mean a pipe comes in. Never give execution rights to files that this data is written into.

Comment: Thanks @Joeri_Damian for the suggestion. i have been using the same in this case.
i was thinking if it possible to  have a encode/decode servlet filters